# How to identify parts in MEF?

Tags: c#, .net, mef

The question is as simple as that: I need some way to identify composable part definitions before actually creating the parts.

In other words, I need to be able to send a string identifying the part to some remote site, which later would send the string back to me, and I should be able to pick that same part based on the string. I do not necessarily need a string (I can build my own map), but I need something that is unique and equality-comparable.

Some things I thought about and rejected:

1. I do realize that the "right" way for doing this is to decorate my parts with metadata, but I don't want to. First, using a meaningful string for identifier means risk of duplication, while using a random one (like GUID) means it would be ugly. Second, my plugins are numerous and I don't want to have to remember about decorating them all the time.
2. Another way that immediately jumps to mind is to use the part's type. However, MEF is generic enough to be above such formalities: a part is not necessarily a .NET class.
3. In trying to "fix" the previous point, I could use type of the actual object that is returned when I go and create the part, but then I would have to create all parts, which are numerous.

Comment: Using a meaningful string risks duplication when naming anything. That's why there's namespaces.

Comment: Applying that to a programming language, like C#, I get compiler checking. The compiler will tell me if there is a conflict. In the absence of such checking, however, duplication is exactly what happens. How many web services did you see with "http://tempuri.org" for namespace? But unlike the web services case, my environment actually requires uniqueness.

Comment: There are catalogs which contain parts, the necessary parts get instantiated _during composition_.  So just because a part is "created" does not mean it is instantiated (if that helps).

Comment: @jberger: I want to identify part definitions, not parts.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin: [Parts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.composition.primitives.composablepart.aspx) have properties to get at their definitions ([ImportDefinitions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.composition.primitives.importdefinition.aspx) and [ExportDefinitions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.composition.primitives.exportdefinition.aspx)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Metadata is really the only viable option, especially if you want the identifier to remain stable over time, e.g. in the face of application restarts or implementation class refactoring/renaming.

If you don't need stability between application restarts, you could either:

- Use MEF 2's `RegistrationBuilder` to programmatically generate the necessary metadata values, e.g. based on an incrementing integer; or,
- Create a custom `[MetadataAttribute]` that does roughly the same thing to generate an id value at runtime

If you need stability between restarts, but not between rebuilds, then using `RegistrationBuilder` to assign ids based on the type name is an option.

Of course, `RegistrationBuilder` is only available in the CodePlex preview builds of MEF 2 or the .NET 4.5 Developer Preview at this point.

TLDR; manually applying metadata attributes is your best bet. In debug mode you could write a post-initialisation routine in your app to ensure uniqueness/presence.

Comment: My chief concern with metadata is that I don't want to burden the plugin developers with that. Trust me, there are some strong reasons :-)

Comment: Just looked at RegistrationBuilder. This looks like exactly what I need at this point. And it will also be handy for some other scenarios where I need to generate metadata. Thanks!